# No overload for method 'Entity' takes 1 arguments in Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0

Within my DBContext i have overriden the `OnModelCreating` method.

The same code works like a charm in .Net Core (by using ModelBuilder) but

on .NET Framework 4 it does not compile.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.CreatedBy)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(500);
        }
    }
```

The error i get is

> No overload for method 'Entity' takes 1 arguments in Entity framework

Unfortunately i cannot figure out what is wrong with this one.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it obvious from the error? Your modelBuilder.Entity() function has no overload that takes in 1 argument and you are passing in one argument. Also check which version of EF you are using on .Net Framework. Is it 6+ or you are using EF Core by mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The same code works like a charm in .Net Core (by using ModelBuilder) but on .NET Framework 4, it does not compile.

In comparison of .net core with .net framework some method implementatios are diffrent. so it's the reason of your compile error. As a solution, just re-write your code as follow:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
.Property(e => e.CreatedBy)
.IsRequired()
.HasMaxLength(500);
```

base your need in the comment, we can manage more than one property in this method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
    {
        entity.Property(e => e.CreatedBy)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(500);

        entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedBy)
        .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

good luck.

Comment: in `OnModelCreating` method, you can repeat this code snippet how many times that you need for different properties, there's no limitation.

I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

EF Core was a complete re-write of Entity Framework; although there are many similarities, much of the entity configuration needs to be done differently.

The above would need to be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .Property(e => e.CreatedBy)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasMaxLength(500);
```